# MenuItem Header starts with _

Tags: wpf, header, menuitem

I have some contextMenu which shows list of object.
My problem is when one of the objects starts with underline ("_") for example : _obj1, 
and the results is that the mentitem displayed without the underline : obj1".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by changing the header template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
     <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,    AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" />
               </DataTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may miss a feature provided by wpf when using a underline-start name.

When you use _obj1, you get the menutime displayed as obj1, but you should try press ALT then you will see the obj1 "underlined" and you can use ALT+o (the first character of the obj name) to "press" the menuitem without using a Mouse.

For example, when you write this:

```
<MenuItem Header="_File">
    <MenuItem .../>
</MenuItem>
```

Then you just see the Menu with "File", but you can use ALT+F as you are clicking this MenuItem.
Just try this and you shall understand.